# High-level API: calling into Odoo models HowTo

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I'm following the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/javascript.html#rpc) and there is the following snippet how to make a query in Odoo v 8.0

```
var Users = new openerp.Model('res.users');

Users.query(['name', 'login', 'user_email', 'signature'])
 .filter([['active', '=', true], ['company_id', '=', main_company]])
 .limit(15)
 .all().then(function (users) {
// do work with users records
});
```

But when i execute that code (with a sample company id), I got everytime the error:

> TypeError: Users.query is not a function

Could someone explain me why and how to make a query in js with odoo?

Answer (score 0):

query() is a shortcut for a builder-style interface to searches (search + read in Odoo RPC terms). It returns a Query() object which is immutable but allows building new Query() instances from the first one, adding new properties or modifiying the parent object's.

so you can use search() or read() instead of query().